# Getting error 'Too Many Values To Unpack' while looping over tensors; unable to use tf.train.batch

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network

When I initialize my Neural Net:

```
print('Checking the Training on a Single Batch...')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        batch_i = 1
        for batch_features, batch_labels in (input_data, input_labels):
            train_neural_network(sess, optimizer, keep_probability, batch_features, batch_labels)
        print('Epoch {:>2}, Batch {}:  '.format(epoch + 1, batch_i), end='')
        print_stats(sess, batch_features, batch_labels, cost, accuracy)
```

I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` on the For Loop.

I figured it might be because I didn't create batches, so I created:

```
tf.train.batch([input_data, input_labels], batch_size, num_threads=1, capacity=32)
```

But I get error:

`TypeError: Cannot convert a list containing a tensor of dtype <dtype: 'uint8'> to <dtype: 'float32'> (Tensor is: <tf.Tensor 'stack_16495:0' shape=(280, 440, 3) dtype=uint8>)`

Both input_data / input_labels is a list of tensors of arrays created using `tf.stack`.

Answer (score 1):

`ValueError:` caused by statement

```
for batch_features, batch_labels in (input_data, input_labels):
```

you needs

```
for batch_features, batch_labels in zip(input_data, input_labels):
```

instead. `(input_data, input_labels)` results in tuple with two elements - `input_data` and `input_labels`. `zip` creates `list` of `tuples` with elements from `input_data` and `input_labels`.
Small example with code

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = (a, b)
d = zip(a, b)
c
Out[16]: ([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
d
Out[17]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Comment: Now I'm getting:
`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 400, 600, 1)'` I get that it's because my label shape is 1d... what would be the best way to change this? My label is currently binary (1 or 0)

Comment: @raph To answer this question I need more code - `train_neural_network` function for example - and more data - shapes of batch_features, batch_labels, dimensions of NN etc. And because this is different problem it's a good idea to open new question.

Comment: Alright thank you so much. I've created a new question and added a github gist of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295607/valueerror-cannot-feed-value-of-shape-0-for-tensor-x0-which-has-shape