# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0,) for Tensor 'x:0', which has shape '(?, 400, 600, 1)'

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network

I get the error above when running my Neural net:

```
print('Checking the Training on a Single Batch...')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        batch_i = 1
        for batch_features, batch_labels in (input_data, input_labels):
            train_neural_network(sess, optimizer, keep_probability, batch_features, batch_labels)
        print('Epoch {:>2}, Batch {}:  '.format(epoch + 1, batch_i), end='')
        print_stats(sess, batch_features, batch_labels, cost, accuracy)
```

Here's the gist to my Neural Network:

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bf557b0fdb9e8c0f8a50b09c2e6eedbc
```

Is there a better way for me to create labels?

Comment: Just like linking to other pages in answers is discouraged because these pages might go away, linking to required information in questions is bad because they might go away or change.

Comment: Print the shape/value of the data you're using in `feed_dict={...}`, you'll almost certainly see something you weren't expecting. Post the result of that if you think it's right.